# Why can't I install bottle on Windows?

Tags: python

I have had problems getting the embedded version of python working with my app. It needs the bottle module, but when I try `pip install bottle` on this machine, I get an error:

```
H:\R.O.S.S\Ross-master\Ross-1.1.0>H:\R.O.S.S\Ross-master\Ross-1.1.0\python\pytho
n.exe -m pip install bottle --no-cache-dir
Collecting bottle
  Downloading bottle-0.12.13.tar.gz (70kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 417kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\*Insert name here*\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6j9e0aut\bottle\s
etup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import bottle
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\*Insert name here*
.SET\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6j9e0aut\bottle\

H:\R.O.S.S\Ross-master\Ross-1.1.0>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is because I don't actually have access to the C drive on this machine. Is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: Try installing the package using virtualenvironment.

Comment: You should be using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win)s.

Comment: How would I do this, @arsho ?

Comment: follow the link @erip posted, it says how to install

Comment: Does anyone know why my question might have got downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a virtual environment in Windows:**

Create a folder and open a command prompt inside this.

Then, create a virtual environment by using: `virtualenv venv`

To use this virtual environment, you need to activate it first. Activate it using: `venv\Source\activate.bat`

Now you will see a `(venv)` prefix in the prompt. That indicates the virtual environment is ready to use. Finally, install packages in this virtual environment as required like this: `pip install bottle`

List the installed packages in a `.txt` file for later: `pip freeze>requirements.txt`

Comment: Using this gives me: `C:\Users*Insert name here*\Downloads\Ross-1.1.0>Python\python.exe -m virtualenv venv
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\*Insert name here*\\Downloads\\Ross-1.1.0\\venv\\python36.zip\\site.py' `

Comment: Could you use the virtualenv? In which step you got this error?

Comment: Have you tried: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments?

Comment: The error is when it tries to read python36.zip. Inside of it, there isn't actually a site.py because it's an embeddable version of python.

Comment: Where did you install Python 3.6? Can you specify your OS environment?

Comment: I'm currently on windows, and with the embeddable version you don't install it. You download + extract the zip file, and you're good to go.

Comment: Sorry. I never used embedded version. Is there any problem using the installer version?

Comment: Yes, I would like the program to be portable so I can place my program + the python embeddable in a folder and run it off a USB stick on any windows machine without having to install python and the rest of my modules.